# C# hiding visibility on part of an enumeration collection / public & private options accessibility

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, enums, scope

The case arises where one wants certain options to be publicly available, but others to only be internally or privately available within an assembly or class respectively.

What is the most elegant way of doing this?

The following would be perfect, but isn't possible:

```
public enum EActions
{
    internal Shutdown,
    Read,
    Write,
    Update
}

...

public void DoSomething(EActions action, int param2, int param3)
{
    // act
}

...

public:

   DoSomething(Read/Write/Update);
```

Comment: As you tagged this question with design-patterns, I recommend that you replace this `enum` with a abstract base class, and replace the items with derived classes. Then create static instances in the base class for each child class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you tagged this question with design-patterns, I recommend that you replace this enum with a abstract base class, and replace the items with derived classes. Then create static instances in the base class for each child class.

```
public abstract class EAction
{
    public abstract void DoYourDeal();


    internal static readonly ShutDownEAction  Shutdown = new ShutDownEAction() ; 
    public static readonly ReadEAction Read = new ReadEAction() ;
    //...
}

    public class ReadEAction : EAction {...}
    public class WriteEAction : EAction {...}
    public class UpdateEAction : EAction {...}
    internal class ShutDownEAction : EAction {...}

public void DoSomething(EAction action)
{
    action.DoYourDeal();
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea, and one I've used. I was hoping there would be a "lighter weight" solution.

Comment: @IanC This is for sure lighter than using enums, beacuse enums always creates switches and other misplaced functions.

Comment: One question I just thought of: how would you call this as if you were passing an enum? In the example you show, it seems to me you'd have to use delegates.

Comment: @IanC I'm not sure if I understood your question. If you want to know which kind of EAction you have, just use `(someAction is ReadEAction)`. But you'll rather just call a method in `someAction`, like `someAction.DoyourDeal()`, and let the runtime find the correct implementation. I don't see any delegates in my code.

Comment: What I mean is the following. Consider that the enum is only 1 of several parameters that one is passing to a method. I can't externally call the methods you show. They are called from within the called method mentioned. Hence the enum to tell it what to call. But if we're not using enums, then AFAIK we'd have to use delegates.

Comment: @IanC I see! The `DoSomething` method shouldn't be aware of what it's doing. Therefore, `param1` & `param2` should be members of EAction, or of a new class, like `class Job { string param1; string param2; EAction action; void DoYourDeal() { action.Run(param1, param2); } }`. Search Google for Command Pattern.

Comment: Ok, I get what you mean. Total encapsulation. But in this case, why even have the DoSomething method when you could just call the final method directly? For the scenario I want (think of passing a command to a DB wrapper), I think a delegate might make more sense. I'll have to investigate a bit more.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/339390/Understanding-and-Implementing-Command-Pattern-in I'll check it out, thanks.

Comment: @IanC Well, i thought DoSomething would control "when" to do something, not "what" to do. Otherwise, you should just call the method, as you said.

Comment: Well, it would control both. Using the enum as an example, one might do s/g like DBCommand(EAction.Insert, "dbname", "tablename", "column", "value");

Comment: You can see here that one wouldn't want EAction.DropTable to be accessible publicly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Extensible enum and control the accessibility as desired.

[Extensible Enum](http://tigerang.blogspot.in/2007/05/simple-design-pattern-for-extensible.html)